# copy the cell value with matching multiple criteria from two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new or intermediate learner to vba programing and came up with a task to copy a cell value from workbook1 of sheet1 to workbook2 of sheet1 by matching up with multiple criteria and copy the Sort reference(workbook1) column cell value to Notes And Assumption(workbook2) cells.

Workbook1 Column                    Workbook2 Column
Functional Group matches with------->   Primary Skills

LOB          matches with------->   Service Line

Region/Country   matches with------->   Work Required Country

Sort Reference(Workbook1)------------------->   Notes And Assumptions(Workbook2)                                                            (**Note:- Matching the criteria and copy the corresponding row Sort Reference value to column Notes and Assumptions**)

Destination Workbook2 Column to match 
[Criteria to match from workbook2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftZzn.png)

Source Workbook1 columns are
[Criteria to match from workbook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rosjl.png)

Demo of Output
[Output of workbook2 in Notes And Assumptions Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X39T.png)
**Note:- Output should be like this as given in Image and if not data found leave blank**

I tried below but not getting the result because if the criteria gets matched and values get pasted in a particular column then that matched row should not repeat again and it starts from the next row to match. Because of this my values get override.

```
   Sub sortref()

Dim wbk, wbk1 As Workbook
Dim sht, sht1 As Worksheet
Dim i, j, k, n, m As Long
Dim FGroup, PSkills, RegCoun, WrCoun, MRCode, RCode As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\611892636\desktop\RMT Changes\RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2.xlsm")
Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2.xlsm").Sheets("Input").Activate

Set sht = Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2.xlsm").Worksheets("Input")
Set sht1 = Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2_OI-408866.xlsb").Worksheets("MUForecasts")

Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2_OI-408866.xlsb").Activate
Workbooks("RMT v8.0.2 - Huawei V1.2_OI-408866.xlsb").Sheets("MUForecasts").Activate

n = sht1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
m = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 13 To m
        For k = 3 To n
            Debug.Print i, k

            FGroup = sht.Range("H" & i)
            PSkills = sht1.Range("R" & k)

            RegCoun = sht.Range("L" & i)
            WrCoun = sht1.Range("P" & k)

            MRCode = sht.Range("X" & i)
            RCode = sht1.Range("Q" & k)

            If FGroup = PSkills Then
               If RegCoun = WrCoun Then
                    If MRCode = RCode Then
                        sht.Cells(i, 2).Copy
                        sht1.Cells(k, 27).Select
                        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    End If
                End If
            End If
         Next k
    Next i

'wbk.Close
Set wbk = Nothing
Set sht = Nothing
Set sht1 = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you take some time to format your tables correctly?

Comment: "Why isn't my code working" isn't a specific enough question.  I think you have the wrong idea about how this site works.   Please see  [help/on-topic] and also [ask] as well as [mcve].  You can [edit] your question to provide the required information, examples and a specific question, and to clean up the formatting.

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry for inconvenience you faced, I have modified the question, please relook....it would be great help.

Comment: Could you show a worked example of data in, to matching criteria logic applied,  to expected data out?

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have put a image of Demo output, in this manner I need the data by matching the 3 criteria which I have mentioned in my query. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an advanced filter approach and tie it into your code.

```
    Sheets("Emps").Range("A1:D8").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Emps").Range("F5:F6"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:B1"), _
    Unique:=False
```

Data to selectively copy:
[image]

Data copied:
[image]

Reference this *short YouTube video*; You can **record a marco to help** yourself **with the code** also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGUKjXmEi2E

A more **thorough tutorial** is found here:
http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html

This tutorial shows how to get the **source data from outside Excel**:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4189-excel-dynamic-filter-to-new-sheet.html

This tutorial shows how to **split data values based on a column to different sheets** (Fruit column; Apple sheet, Pear sheet, etc.):
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2884-excel-save-filtered-data-new-sheet-workbook.html

Comment: Thanks for help, but my requirement is different as I have to match the criteria of column value with the output file and if it match then I have to paste the Sort Reference row value of that particular value and paste to the output file of column Notes And Assumptions. I have posted the image with demo output file.